# how to constuct a matrix in mathematica with rows defined by different rules?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to create a matrix 2 by 3 such that first row is defined by f(i) and second row is defined by g(i) using Table command. for example

```
sin[1]  sin[2]  sin[3]

cos[1]  cos[2]  cos[3]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In[1]:= {Array[Sin, 3], Array[Cos, 3]}
Out[1]= {{Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3]},
         {Cos[1], Cos[2], Cos[3]}}
```

Watch out for exactly correct capitalization and exactly correct use of () versus [] versus {} and = versus := versus == and there is even an === and those are all different. Make any error in any one of those and you will get incorrect results or error messages you don't know how to interpret or even nothing at all.